# При пользовании postgres через консоль не корректно отображаются русские символы

Tags: postgresql, кодировка, консоль

[image: Вывод консоли]

На днях случайно удалил переменные окружения, когда добавлял новую переменную. Раньше использовал команду "chcp 1251" и все хорошо работало, русские символы отображались прекрасно. После удаления переменных окружения все отображается как на скрине. Переменные окружения добавил обратно, те что использую и те, что должны быть по дефолту. Но видимо нужна какая то еще.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, что нужно добавить или как справиться с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить:

```
psql -d yourbase -U yourlogin
```

и установить кодировку:

```
set client_encoding='win1251';
```

Comment: Пробовал, тоже не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился добавлением некоторых переменных окружения, которые отсутствовали у меня. Посмотрел у коллег на компе и добавил.
Далее выполнил инструкции отсюда https://iu5bmstu.ru/index.php/PostgreSQL_-_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_psql_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_Windows
В итоге все заработало как и прежде.
Всем удачи. Не удаляйте свои переменные окружения, как я)))))
[image: Итог]
[image: Переменные окружения]

Answer (score 0):

Из `psql`-клиента кодировку "win1251" можно установить командой:

```
\! chcp 1251
```